# Avoid Null Value with Passing String Query to Generic Handler From webpage - asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i'm using `generic handler` to get image from  `MySql` DB i use this code to code the image ..

> **Edited** : i'v used  `IRequiresSessionState` to get Query As Session but i still get `null` value as shown [image]

```
                    string Key= Request.QueryString["Key"].ToString();
                Session["KeyImage"] = Key;
```

.

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)


    {
                    string Key= Request.QueryString["Key"].ToString();
        string ConnectionString = @"Server=MYSQL5011.Smarterasp.net;Database=db_9d6c52_ahmed;Uid=9d6c52_ahmed;Pwd=123123123;";
        MySqlConnection GetConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        GetConnection.Open();
        string VoiceorScreenSearch = "Select * From User where User_Stat=@UserStat";
        MySqlCommand Comand = new MySqlCommand(VoiceorScreenSearch, GetConnection);
        Comand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"UserStat",Key);
        MySqlDataAdapter DA = new MySqlDataAdapter(Comand);
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DA.Fill(DT);
        byte[] Image = (byte[]) DT.Rows[0][1];
        context.Response.ContentType = "Image/jpg";
        context.Response.ContentType = "Image/jpeg";
        context.Response.ContentType = "Image/PNG";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(Image);
        context.Response.Flush();



    }
```

this is my controller image

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1"  ImageUrl="HandlerImage.ashx" runat="server"></asp:Image>
```

and  this is my `load page` where i can retrieve my `Query` it's public because i tried to inherent from it  ! but i got not thing useful !

```
   public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String Key= Request.QueryString["Key"].ToString();
        TestConnection TrytoSearchforData = new TestConnection();
        TrytoSearchforData.TestUser(Key);

    }
```

any ideas  i will be grateful .. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you forget `Key` within your Controller
it mus be like

```
    <asp:Image OnLoad="Image1_Load2" ID="Image1"  Width="20%"  ImageUrl="HandlerImage.ashx?Key='<%Eval("Key")%> CssClass="fancybox" runat="server"></asp:Image>
```

or you Can pass its Parameter on page load  with this

```
                            Image1.ImageUrl = "HandlerImage.ashx?Key=" + Request.QueryString["Key"].ToString();
```

This **Should** work :)